# Nesting XSL element: nesting xsl:if in xsl:template name="xxxx"

Tags: xslt

i keep getting XSLT errors for :

```
<xsl:template name="PermissionsHeader">
  <xsl:if test="true">
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there some kind of precedence where xsl:if cannot be nested in xsl:template? all i want is some condition in xsl:template...thanks

Error message:

```
Error on line 1 column 1 
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Premature end of file.
```

Comment: XSLT errors...which isnt very descriptive :\   i also have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802667/passing-a-param-from-xsltemplate-and-using-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="true"> 
</xsl:if>
```

see [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N8413.html)

Comment: please upvote...someone downvoted me needlessly :\    i also have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802667/passing-a-param-from-xsltemplate-and-using-it