# passing a string param from xsl:template and using it in another xsl file

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:template match="HtmlCode">
    <xsl:copy-of select="child::*|text()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="HappyFriend">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'i am a friggin' RRRRROOOOOOOVVVERRRRR~~'"/>
</xsl:call-template> 

<xsl:template name="HappyFriend">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <HtmlCode>
            &lt;span&gt; &lt;%="text"%&gt;   &lt;/span&gt;
        </HtmlCode>
<xsl:template>
```

somehow i keep getting XSLT issues...all i am trying to do is to get the value of the variable "text" which is "i am a frigggin RRROVERRR" to appear into a i am a frigggggin' RRROOOVVVERRRR~~ in the "HappyFriend" template.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several problems:

-- The string literal `'i am a friggin' RRRRROOOOOOOVVVERRRRR~~'` contains unbalanced single quotes.  You probably want

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select='"i am a friggin&#x27; RRRRROOOOOOOVVVERRRRR~~"'/>
```

-- The `call-template` cannot occur outside of a template definition.

-- To refer to the parameter you should be using `value-of-select`, as in

```
 &lt;span&gt; &lt;%="<xsl:value-of select="$text"/>"%&gt;   &lt;/span&gt;
```

Comment: Can also use "'...'" apart from '"..."' if you prefer
or use <xsl:variable name="x" select="'...'"/> and then later on <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$x"/> to pass that value. Checkout https://clipflair.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/ClipFlair.Gallery/collection/activities_list.xsl for example after <xsl:template match="cxml:Item" mode="col">

Answer (score 2):

**Here is one correct way to do what I guess you want:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="HtmlCode">
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::*|text()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="HappyFriend">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select='"i am a friggin&apos; RRRRROOOOOOOVVVERRRRR~~"'/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="HappyFriend">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <HtmlCode>
          <span><xsl:value-of select="$text"/></span>
    </HtmlCode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (none has been provided!!!):

```
<HtmlCode/>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<HtmlCode>
   <span>i am a friggin' RRRRROOOOOOOVVVERRRRR~~</span>
</HtmlCode>
```

Answer (score 1):

see the [FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5982.html) for parameters

```
   <xsl:template name="HappyFriend"> 
         <xsl:param name="text"/> 
         <HtmlCode> 
             <span> 
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/> 
             </span> 
        </HtmlCode>  
     <xsl:template>
```